# LG G Pro E980 stuck loop on TWRP openrecovery script

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, lg

My LG G Pro E980 is rooted. It was working fine. Today I did factory reset to reset phone and delete data. But after restarting it has got stuck on TWRP openrecovery script, showing errors and keeps restarting.
This is the screenshot of the problem:
[image]

Anyone please help!

Comment: Did you issue the factory reset from Settings app? If yes, then setup [tag:adb] in PC, boot device into TWRP, connect device to PC and using adb delete everything under Cache partition. Now reboot again into TWRP and use its factory reset option.

Comment: Yes I did reset from Settings. Device is not booting into TWRP. It boots directly into the openrecovery script (above screenshot) and then it restarts. It happens in loop continuously.

Comment: Have you able to solve this problem and get your phone fixed? I have exactly the same problem and desperate for some help. Will you please let me know ASAP? Thanks, Bill

Comment: so did u fix it.
im having the same problem so ....

Comment: @BrickedGPro, I wasn't able to resolve it myself. I took it to a mobile repair shop, and the guy resolved it in half an hour. I don't know how he did it.

Comment: @ezg Check my comment above.